# Why am I suddenly unable to focus with with Olympus OM-2 prism?

Tags: troubleshooting, manual-focus, olympus, focusing-screen

Somehow the prism for focusing in my Olympus OM-2 changed. The prism lost all its structure and what is left is a round grid structure with a divided circle in the middle, that is changing its brightness from one side bright and one side dark to one side dark and one side bright depending on my angle of looking into the viewfinder.

Anybody knows what happened and how to repair it?

[image: thats how it looks]

Comment: Did you try a different lens? It may be your lens is manually stopped down or stuck. It can also happen with a lens with a slow aperture like f/5.6 or f8

Comment: Take care with terminology - you mention the "prism" but you're talking about the focusing screen. The prism is part of the viewing system, but separate from the focusing screen. The focusing screen has a microprism ring and a split-image central section. Take a look at: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Focusing_screen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Focusing_screen)

Answer (score 1):

The focusing screen that came as standard with the OM-2 was number 1-13, "Olympus 1-13 Microprism Horizontal Split Image Matte Focusing Screen". It was designed for general use with a wide range of lenses. The diagram of the screen shows its three zones:

[image: Olympus focusing screen 1-13]

In the center is a split-ring rangefinder for critical focusing. Around that is a microprism collar for rapid focusing. The rest of the screen is a matte surface for focusing in situations wher the other parts don't do well.

Long lenses and low light make the rangefinder and microprism dark and hard to see. You can see in your photo that the rangefinder has been rendered useless by blacking out the lower half. In this case for critical focusing you'd have to rely on the microprism.

These sections of the ground glass are not nearly as visible under bright lighting conditions, and the use of normal to wide angle lenses. You may not have noticed the different zones if you have been mainly using the camera in brightly lit conditions.

Olympus made many different focusing screens for different situations. Most non-professionals never had the need for one different than the standard.